# Отправка писем по шаблону

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно мне решить задачу такую.
На сайте есть таблица, которая подгружается по ajax (офферы с данными)
Нужно вытягивать с определенных div'ов переменные, в том числе e-mail
и потом высылать шаблон на те же имейлы которые будут вытянуты.

Поскажите куда копать и с чего начать реализацию такого проэкта.

Сначала думал с помощью javascript вытягивать эти значения, а потом посылать их в клас php (например php_libmail класс для отправки писем) и чтобы высылался e-mail.

Посоветуйте знающие люди какими иструментами пользоватся для реализации этой задачи.

Нужно высылать много писем которые постоянно подгружаются...

Comment: А сайт ваш или чужой?

Comment: Сайт не мой а чужой.

Comment: Помогать создавать спам бота не охота))